# Android- Show custom dialog at position where a marker is clicked on map

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, google-maps-markers, infowindow

How can i display a custom dialog at the coordinates where a marker is clicked on Map. Currently I am able to display a dialog of my choice but it's position is not at the exact place.
   Following is the sample of code:

```
  LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);

    Dialog alertD = new Dialog(context);
    alertD.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    alertD.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    alertD.getWindow().setLayout(40, 40);

    Point markerScreenPosition = mMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());

    WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = alertD.getWindow().getAttributes();

    wmlp.x = markerScreenPosition.x;
    wmlp.y = markerScreenPosition.y;
```

Comment: you cannot do like this, since mapview is a view from google layer and the position wont accurate with the marker position you have clicked.

Comment: Why don't you use InfoWindowView of google map?

Comment: Thanks.I can't use InfoWindowView because the design of info window is a bit complex in my case.Different buttons on transparent layout are required around the marker. (I have sorted it out by getting the coordinates by onTouchListener for the moment).